# Change order of columns in stacked bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I'm using the following code to produce a stacked bar plot from a pandas data frame in Python (`data` is the DataFrame object).

```
data.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(15, 10), x='Species', fontsize=16,
          rot=0)
```

Here is [an IPython Notebook](https://gist.github.com/standage/9f66e35754a79e63d1a7) for context.

I would like to change the order of the columns. The `seaborn.barplot` function has the `x_order` argument, which does exactly what I would like. However, it does not support stacked bar plots directly like the `pandas.DataFrame.plot` function does. What is the simplest way to reorder the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually rearrange the rows by permuting the numeric indices, like the answer given by @iayork, or alternatively you can set the index of your dataframe to be the column `Species`.

```
species = ['A', 'B', 'H', 'S', 'P', 'N']

data2 = data.set_index(['Species'])
data2.reindex(species).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(15, 10),
                            fontsize=16, rot=0)
```

By setting the index of `data` as `Species`, you can now permute the rows by their string labels, instead of numeric indices.

Comment: Minor point, you don't need to make the index "Species" to permute by label.  In my answer, the indices are actually being ordered by label, not index, because I use ".loc" instead of ".iloc"; it's just the that label happened to correspond with the index to start with.  Agreed that the result could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to rearrange your index.

```
data2 = data.loc[[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

reverses the order in dataframe and plot.